# Manipulate json data, into a new json array

Tags: php, json

```
  {
    "name": "2Pac",
    "album": "All Eyez on Me",
    "track": "All Eyez on Me",
    "duration": "5:08",
    "trackNo": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "2Pac",
    "album": "2Pac Greatest Hits",
    "track": "Keep Ya Head Up",
    "duration": "4:24",
    "trackNo": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "2Pac",
    "album": "2Pac Greatest Hits",
    "track": "2 Of Amerikaz Most Wanted",
    "duration": "4:07",
    "trackNo": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "50 Cent",
    "album": "Get Rich Or Die Tryin%27",
    "track": "P.I.M.P.",
    "duration": "4:10",
    "trackNo": "11"
  },
  {
    "name": "50 Cent",
    "album": "Get Rich Or Die Tryin%27",
    "track": "Like My Style",
    "duration": "3:13",
    "trackNo": "12"
  },
```

I have lots of json data formatted this way and was looking for a way to manipulate the data so that it only has one artist name and then the albums for that artist then songs within each album. PHP would be fine so I can convert things, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use these:

- json_decode
- array_map, array_filter, for loops, what you like
- json_encode

Basically it boils down to:

- parse
- mangle
- format

I'll leave the exercise to you, but browsing these functions and similar questions here should get you started. If you have anything to show then, you may ask for more specific help.